# How to load a DLL file to determine its dependent assembly names?

Tags: c#, reflection

At run time I want to load an assembly and need to find the names of its dependent assemblies, so that I can determine which assemblies are required to execute the given DLL file.

Comment: I guess you will need to check on [`GetReferencedAssemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanx for replay. But my question is that, i have an assembly Account.dll and m using four another assemblies as a reference assembly. If i provide only Account.dll to other, then how can other person know that which assemblies are required to load Account.dll

Comment: So, you didn't read the linked documentation at all, did you.

Comment: Yep, i have seen that document, and example was given to get details about loaded current assembly. But i want load new one. I found answer.

    Assembly _Assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(@"H:\Account.dll");
    AssemblyName[] _AN = _Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();

Comment: You can do this with Mono.Cecil without having the other assemblies present.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to load the assembly (DLL file) into a [Reflection-Only context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172331.aspx).

After that you can use [`GetReferencedAssembles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to find dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

I used this some time ago in a nasty bit of code:

Where you load your assembly, register the resolve event:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += Assemblies_AssemblyResolve;
Assembly.LoadFile("<path to your assembly>");
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= Assemblies_AssemblyResolve;
```

The resolve event handler is called for every referenced dll. here i try to load the assembly.

```
Assembly Assemblies_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.RequestingAssembly != null)
    {
        return LoadAssemblyFromPath(new AssemblyName(args.Name), args.RequestingAssembly.Location);
    }

    if (assemblyTryPath != null)
    {
        return LoadAssemblyFromPath(new AssemblyName(args.Name), assemblyTryPath);
    }

    return null;
}
```

And a little helper where the actual loading happens:

```
private Assembly LoadAssemblyFromPath(AssemblyName assemblyName,string fullPath)
{
    if (assemblyName == null||fullPath==null)
        return null;

    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
    string dllName = assemblyName.Name + ".dll";
    string fullPath2Try = Path.Combine(path, dllName);

    Assembly loadedAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(fullPath2Try);

    return loadedAssembly;
}
```

Hope, that helps!

Comment: both of the `else` keywords are redundant, since you have a `return` statement in the `if` cases. that is, `else {` and it's accompanied `}` can be removed. This is of course a matter of coding taste, but I enjoy nest-free code

Comment: you are completely right! this is a relic from times where the code was not split up to nice little methods (and i was still experimenting). will update the answer

Answer (score 1):

I found answer. If we want to find the Referenced assemblies of unloaded assembly, we can find from following way.

```
Assembly _Assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(@"H:\Account.dll");
AssemblyName[] _AN = _Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();
```